# Create serial field following alphabetical order with QGIS using graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

I have a field with names, a string field, and I want to create another one with serial content following the alphabetical order.

I have this:

---

### |Field1|

### |  B   |

### |  C   |

### |  A   |

### |  D   |

And I want to reach this:

---

### |Field1| Field2 |

### |  A   |    1   |

### |  B   |    2   |

### |  C   |    3   |

### |  D   |    4   |

The MMQGIS plugin offers a tool to sort Shapefiles, but is this operation not possible directly in the field calculator? 
I'm very interested to know how to make this to make a model in the graphical modeller

Comment: [related answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279177/93656) for QGIS3

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for QGIS 2.x, try

- *Toolbox* -> *QGIS Geoalgorithms*-> *Execute SQL*

  - *Additional input datasources* -> choose your layer
  - *SQL Query* -> `SELECT * FROM input1 ORDER BY Field1`

(This creates a new temporary layer)

- *Field Calculator* -> *Create a new field* -> `@row_number`

or

- *Layer* -> *Add Layer* -> *Add/Edit Virtual Layer*

  - *Import* -> choose your layer
  - *Query* -> `SELECT * FROM <your_layer_name> ORDER BY Field1`
- add `@row_number` as above

Comment: ...seems odd that I don't know a more elegant solution to this, despite working with QGIS for ages. anybody else?