# Sort selected points by latitude/northing with field calculator

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have bathimetry data in .shp format. The points (picture below shows one of multiple groups/profiles) do not have ID numbers and are randomly dispersed through the attribute table.

[image]
[image]

I have selected each group and added group ID to it. Now each point has "Sort" attribute that serves as the group ID. I still need each individual point to have ID number within the group.

I need these points numbered starting with the northernmost point in group (Field2 in attribute table is northing) and ending with the southernmost. So, a point with highest "Field2" value gets value of 1 in "point_num" field.

Basically, what I need to  do is sort selected points according to value of "Field2" attribute. How can I do this with (preferably) QGIS field calculator or some other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS 3.0, there is a tool `Order by expression` which enables you to sort a field Ascending or Descending:

[image]

The Ascending is selected by default. If you want Descending just deselect Ascending and it should work.

The tool can be accessed from `Processing Toolbox -> Vector General -> Order by expression`

Comment: Ok, this sorting tool works, thanks! Is it possible to do this in existing layer without creating a new one? Also, I need to add numbers from 1 to 55 to these "point_num" attribute after ordering by 1.2 "Field2".

Comment: No. The tool creates a new file which is very common when dealing with processing tools. If this answer solved your problem, please accept it and if you have a new question, it is better to ask on separate thread.